# Creating android content provider by "extending" / "not extending" ContentProvider class

Tags: android

Q-1 - To create my own Content Provider class, when I should extend ContentProvider class and when I should not extend ContentProvider class ?

Q-2 - If I create Content Provider without CONTENT_URI(like many other built-in content providers in android.provider.*, how will I use managedQuery(...) or query(....).

I have seen response to similar question in [this question on content provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358459/content-provider-in-android-basic-questions) but I am not sure they answer it completly.

Comment: Can someone please respond...? If it is very basic OR Wrong question please put one word "Basic" or "Wrong" at least.

Comment: I've responded. If it answered your question, can you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Even with extension you'd be implementing the methods anyway. A `ContentProvider` allows you to actually use the internal system for Android to access data from different places in your application. Basically, if you are storing data, extend the `ContentProvider` and use either  `ContentResolver.query` or `Activity.managedQuery` to access that data.

2) AFAIK (and this could be wrong), you need a CONTENT_URI when you create a `ContentProvider`. This is how the `ContentResolver` knows where it should be pulling from and one way to allow your application to even access that data (through the application manifest). So, use a CONTENT_URI. There isn't much of a reason not to IMO.